# Pseudocode for an output statement

Tags: pseudocode

How would I write `System.out.println("Marvin has " + total + " coins in total");` in pseudocode for an algorithm?

I feel like `Print "Marvin has" + total + " coins in total` is not really pseudocode?

This is for an algorithm question on a first year Java assignment

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) might be of help.

Comment: Why do you consider that not pseudocode?

Comment: Normally, when writing pseudocode, those details are neglected (after all, the output is just for us humans and is not essential for the computation). Also, where is the connection to Java? Pseudocode is meant to be language-independent.

Comment: Not really sure! I didn't know if it was okay to use the + in a print statement like that, but if it is then i'll leave it like it is!

Comment: the only example I was given was:

    Print "The total is ", total

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode is designed to be human readable. There are no rules for what is and isn't "too close to actual code," just as long as it suits your audience. Usually, I try to write as if someone with zero coding experience is reading it, because that's what my clients would prefer. They might have no clue why there are `"` in that statement or what string concatenation is.

I would just write:

```
Print the total number of coins Marvin has to the console.
```

The best advice is to use what will make sense to those who are going to read it. It you're writing the pseudo-code for another Java programmer, they would have no issue with what you posted.